# Should I explicitly set thread reference to null after thread completes it's work?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Should I explicitly set thread reference to null after thread completes it's work or it's not necessary? If I want to set it as null then where in the code should I do this?

Should I check if thread is alive or not using `thread.isalive` flag and then set it to null if it's not alive?

Comment: Why do you want to set the reference to null at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is what i am asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should i explicitly set thread reference to null after thread
>   completes it's work or it's not necessary?

Personally, I would not bother. There are a few cases where explicitly setting object references to null really matters anyway. Regardless of type those cases are:

- If the variable is a static member and the object it references consumes a lot of memory.
- If the variable is an instance member contained within a longer living object which references an object that consumes a lot of memory.
- If the variable is a local to a long running method which references an object that consumes a lot of memory.<sup>1</sup>

Those are the ones I could think of. Perhaps there are more, but probably not many. The common denominator here is that the variable references an object that consumes a lot of memory. The managed `Thread` object itself is not going to consume a lot of memory so I cannot imagine that setting a variable of type `Thread` to null is going to accomplish a whole lot for you regardless of how it is used. Most of the resources are allocated when the thread starts and then get deallocated when the thread ends.

> Should i check if thread is alive or not using thread.isalive flag and
>   then set it to null if it's not alive.

I prefer to use `Thread.Join` to test and wait for the completion of a thread. In fact, I have *never* used `Thread.IsAlive` for anything useful...ever.

---

<sup>1</sup>*The GC is actually smart enough to dispose local object references before a method ends if it can detect that the reference is no longer used.*

Answer (score 3):

You should treat a Thread like any other object:
keep a reference only as long as you need it (for example for a `Join()` ).

When you do have a long-living reference t a Thread (ie in a static field) then you should set it to `null` when you no longer need it. But much better not tho have such a variable.

Comment: It would be relevant to know what variable(s) the Original Poster holds the reference in. A local variable, or an instance field (on what object) or a static field?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It's a static field

Comment: @Charu - then try to redesign and get rid of it.